# Interpreting two wires on 1 pin within this diagram

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm trying to interpret this diagram and wondering if there is a way around needing anything special.

I have a Pi that I'm attempting to hook up to this leveler into an RFID sensor.

[image]

I notice that this red cable is bridged from the sensor to the Pi, but I don't understand how this link happens. Is there a way around this?

Comment: It’s a 3V3 to 5V logic level shifter for the UART. Why is that a problem?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Sorry, I'm just asking good wire splitting solution as I spliced 2 female cables and wired them to the pin. Just seems hacky and wanted to learn a better approach.

Comment: all those plug cables are dodgy,  going via a solderless breadboard will allow moere fan-out,  soldering wires would be more reliable.

Comment: I wouldn't attempt to interpret that "diagram", I'd ask for a proper schematic instead.

Comment: This wiring diagram is not logical.  You can reroute  the paths for Vcc and Gnd to make it neater. P3 is the Analog RF Pwr/Gnd and P1 is the UART port. There has to be a better way, but hard to find on this 5yr old board

Comment: So I got this thing working, I took scissors and spliced the wires to connect them and wrapped around the pin. RFID is working, but just wondering better approach. I want this thing to end up in a small enclosure, so not sure if I want a breadboard.

Comment: Thanks @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 any chance you would be able to show me in a diagram how the rerouting would work? Not sure I completely follow

Answer (score 1):

[image]
This is another logical equivalent using a different level shift and grounds and other variations are Ok since there are extra common pins.

The physical wiring may be solid or stranded AWG24 but should be robust with minimum exposed conductors unless you intend to poke them thru a couple mm for test probes.  Strain relief is often done to protect fragile connections from fatigue after several bends.

Learn to solder by pre-tinning contacts at both ends so the contact solder joint time can be done in less than 2~3 seconds to avoid stress on plated thru-holes to pads.

Comment: Great, thanks for taking the time to do this. My question is.. this is purely for cleanup, correct? I was curious if there was a way to avoid needing to splice the wires where the red wire exists. Your approach definitely seems cleaner though.

Comment: Yes many ways to route 5V like resistor wire as a pin in P3 and wrap and continue to P1.